# Quand utiliser « tiers/tierce » ou « troisième » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, adjectifs, nombres

La citation ci-après provient de la page 91 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> In certain fixed expressions, *tiers* and *tierce* are used instead of troisième.
>
> - le tiers état
>     *the third estate*
> - une tierce personne
>     *a third party*
> - le tiers-monde
>     *the third world*

Dans le wiktionnaire, à [tiers](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tiers), on trouve :

> Tiers (nom)
>
> 1. […]
> 2. Troisième personne.
>      *Il survint un tiers.*
>      *Il se mit en tiers avec tel et tel.*
>      *J’étais en tiers avec eux.*
> 3. […]
> 4. Troisième situation.
>      *Le principe du tiers exclus*.

et:

> Tiers (adjectif)
>
> 1. Troisième.

Pour je ne sais quelle raison, Crocker ne donne jamais de précisions sur ces exemples. Quand employer « tiers/tierce » et quand employer « troisième » ? Quelle est la différence ?

Answer (score 7):

*Tiers* (comme ordinal, pas comme fraction) est une survivance et ne s'emploie guère en dehors des quelques expressions consacrées où il est présent que pour y faire allusion (*tiers monde*, l'expression la plus récente est visiblement une allusion à *tiers état*).

La série des ordinaux dont tiers fait partie est *prime*, *second*, *tiers*, *quart*, *quint* (Charles Quint par exemple), *sixte*, *septime*, *octave*, *none*, *décime*. À part *second*, les autres sont rares (sauf en math et en musique, mais l'origine y est perdue).  Les adverbes *primo*, *secundo*, *tertio*, *quarto*, *quinto*, *sexto*, *septimo*, *octavo*, *nono*, *decimo* sont plus courants.

Comme fraction on a *le tout*, *la moitié*, *le tiers*, *le quart*, *le cinquième*, …

Answer (score 3):

Je ne crois pas que tiers soit une survivance ; je pense que c'est un mot qui s'emploie toujours, avec différents sens, et qui forme toujours des locutions.

Exemple de locution remise à la mode récemment : le *tiers-temps*. (locution qui a d'ailleurs de nombreuses significations aussi).

Simplement il s'emploie moins souvent que troisième, c'est tout.

Il veut principalement dire que quelque chose est divisé en trois parties égales, et qu'on en prend une des parts : *Je prendrai le tiers de cette tarte*.

Troisième se rapporte plus à une énumération : *Il est ressuscité le troisième jour après sa mort*.

Answer (score -1):

De manière générale, sauf dans quelques expressions figée (tu en listes probablement la majorité), utilise troisième. Tiers/tierce n’est plus vraiment utilisé.